# How to count all HTTP/HTTPS requests made by Java application?

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to count the number of HTTP requests made by my Java application, but I'm running into some challenges. I'm using different libraries and classes to make the requests, and I'm not sure if they all use `HttpURLConnection` under the hood.

- I tried using Wireshark, but since my requests are HTTPS, I can only detect [TCP + TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985246/wireshark-http-filter-not-working-on-macos), which makes it hard to separate them from other requests made by my system. I know I could filter by source IP, but it is one more pain.
- I also tried manually adding counters with `AtomicInteger`  but I would need to add it in many places, and I may miss some calls:

```java
AtomicInteger requests = new AtomicInteger(0);
requests.incrementAndGet();
```

Is there an easier approach to count all HTTP/HTTPS requests made by my Java application? Thank you for your help!